# PHP ftp_nlist returning false when retrieving large directory?

Tags: php, directory, ftp

**What I'm trying to do:**
Use PHP ftp_nlist to retrieve the contents of a directory on the FTP server

**The problem:**
For directories that contain a lot of files (the one I encountered the problem on has nearly 40 thousand files, and no subfolders), the ftp_nlist function is returning false.  For directories that are not as large, the ftp_nlist function returns an array of filenames as expected.

**What I've tried:**

- Enabling passive mode (it already was enabled, but I see it as a common suggestion)
- Adding ftp_set_option($conn_id, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false); after my ftp_login
- using ftp_chdir, although my folder names never have spaces anyways
- echoing error_get_last() after ftp_nlist returns false.  The error show seems unrelated, but is shown below.
  [image: Here is the error I'm getting. For context, my PHP version is 5.5.16]

**My code:**
In case it is useful, here is the function I have created.  What it is supposed to do is...

- take in $fm (filemaker, unrelated to this problem)
- take in $FTPConnectionID (the ftp connection I established in the prior to the function call)
- take in $FolderPath (the path of the folder on the FTP server for which I want to list files/subfolders recursively - ex: "SomeFolder/Testing")
- take in $TextFile (I am writing the paths of every file found on the FTP server to a text file, which was created prior to calling the function)

```
function createAuditFile($fm, $FTPConnectionID, $FolderPath, $TextFile) {
    echo "createAuditFile called for " . $FolderPath . "\n";
    //Get the contents of the given path.  Will include files and folders.
    $FolderContents = ftp_nlist($FTPConnectionID, $FolderPath);
    if($FolderContents == false) {
        echo "Couldn't get " . $FolderPath . "\n";
        echo "ERROR: " . print_r(error_get_last()) . "\n";
    } else {
        print_r($FolderContents);
    }
        
    //Loop through the array, call this function recursively if a folder is found.
    
    if(is_array($FolderContents)) {
        foreach($FolderContents as $Content) {
            //Create a varaible for the folder path
            $ContentPath = $FolderPath . "/" . $Content;

            //Call the function recursively if a folder is found
            if(pathinfo($Content, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "") {
                createAuditFile($fm, $FTPConnectionID, $ContentPath, $TextFile);
                echo "Recursive call for " . $ContentPath . "\n";
            //If a file is found, add the file ftp path to our array
            } else {
                echo "Writing to file: " . $ContentPath . "\n";
                fwrite($TextFile, $ContentPath . "\n");
            }

        }
    }
    
}
```

I can provide other code if needed, but I think my question is less of a coding issue, and more of an understanding ftp_nlist issue.  I've been stuck on this for hours, so any help is appreciated.  And like I said, this function works just fine for most folder paths passed to it, the problem is when there are tens of thousands of files within the folder.  Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ftp\_nlist limiting out put to 9999 elements in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201652/ftp-nlist-limiting-out-put-to-9999-elements-in-the-array)

Comment: Can you retrieve the listing of large folders using any commandline/GUI FTP client? (running on the same machine as your PHP code) + Did you try setting `FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC`? + We need [mcve] (that means all your FTP code, and no code after `ftp_nlist`).